# Qual a forma mais prática de mudar o sinal de uma variável numérica para positivo?

Tags: python-3.x

Isto é, quando o número da variável é gerado aleatoriamente, podendo ser positivo ou negativo:

Atualmente estou usando:

```
if number < 0 :
    number = number* -1
```

Comment: A ironia é que sou brasileiro

Answer (score 1):

Calculando o valor absoluto do número com a função [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs):

```
numero = abs(numero)
```

Por definição, o retorno de `abs` sempre será positivo.

```
assert abs(1) == 1
assert abs(0) == 0
assert abs(-1) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

No modulo [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/operator.html#operator.neg) existe a função `neg()` no qual nos permite aplicar uma negação aritmética, que consiste na inversão do sinal.

Importe a função `neg()` do modulo `operator`:

```
from operator import neg
```

Veja o exemplo:

```
num = -205
num = neg(num)

print(num)
```

Saída:

> 205

E o mesmo funciona para valores positivos:

```
numP = 221
numP = neg(numP)

print(numP)
```

Saída:

> -221

Comment: Vlw, já é mais simples do que o  jeito que eu estava fazendo.

Mas e se num / numP precisasse sempre ser convertido para positivo quando negativo. Mas não devesse ser convertido para negativo quando positivo ? Nesse caso, todo num / numP positivo deveria ser ignorado ... Algma dica ?

Comment: @VitorOliveira não entendi muito bem, vc quer remover o sinal só se for negativo? Se sim, faça um teste `neg(num) if num < 0 else num`.